# Can NOT authorize calling Script for new ScriptDb when Included Library remains from previously deleted ScriptDb.

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization, shared-libraries, libraries

I deleted a ScriptDb BEFORE I removed its reference from the Resources -> Installed Libraries of the calling script.

I created a new ScriptDb with the same name as the old ScriptDb.

When I run the calling script, I get the following message:
Library with identifier libraryDb is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)

When I open Resources -> Installed Libraries in the calling script, I get the following message:
We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

And when I click on the  Included Libraries -> Title's link: libraryDb in the calling script, I get the following message:
Library with identifier MJYZ65NimkGffbICkW9uVWAfx44b5R80M is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)

---

Steps to reproduce the problem.

1. Create and Publish the following ScriptDB named libraryDb:

   function getDb() {
       return ScriptDb.getMyDb();
   }
2. Create and Publish the following calling script named callingScript:

   function callingScript() {
     var retLibDb = libraryDb.getDb();
     var dbRecord = { name: 'myName' };
     retLibDb.save( dbRecord);
   }
3. Include the LibraryDb in the calling script (Resources -> Installed Libraries) using the libraryDb project key.
4. Run the callingScript to authorize and use the libraryDb.
5. Delete the libraryDb (Code.gs -> File -> Delete).
6. Create and Publish the following new ScriptDB named libraryDb (same name as first):

   function getDb() {
     return ScriptDb.getMyDb();
   }
7. In the calling script's Installed Libraries (Resources -> Installed Libraries) remove the old libraryDb reference.
8. In the calling script's Installed Libraries (Resources -> Installed Libraries) add the new libraryDb reference.
9. Run the callingScript.

   ---

I expect an authorization dialog to appear and let me authorize and run the callingScript.

I get the following messages:
Library with identifier libraryDb is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)

Open the calling script's Resources -> Libraries… get the following message:
We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

Click on: Included Libraries -> Title's link: libraryDb, get the following message:
Library with identifier MJYZ65NimkGffbICkW9uVWAfx44b5R80M is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)

---

I'm running:
Machine: MacBook Pro
OS: OS X 10.7.5
Browser: Safari V  6.0.4 (7536.29.13)